# How to display different images for annotations according to string value

Tags: ios, xcode, image, annotations, plist

I have A MapView with multiple annotations. I need to put different images to annotations according to string value in my data.plist

My current code (work just for one category, one image):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[anns objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"]];

    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
```

My plist file construction:

[image: plist]

**EDIT**

My MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];


    NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];

    NSLog(@" MapView is %@",mapView);
    NSLog(@"anns is: %@", anns);



    for(int i = 0; i < [anns count]; i++) {


        NSString *coordinates = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

        double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
        double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

        MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
        theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;


        //calculate distance
        CLLocationCoordinate2D annocoord = myAnnotation.coordinate;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D usercoord = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;

        NSLog(@"ANNO  = %f, %f", annocoord.latitude, annocoord.longitude);
        NSLog(@"USER = %f, %f", usercoord.latitude, usercoord.longitude);

        CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:myAnnotation.coordinate.latitude longitude:myAnnotation.coordinate.longitude];
        CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        NSLog(@"LOC  = %f, %f", loc.coordinate.latitude,  loc.coordinate.longitude);
        NSLog(@"LOC2 = %f, %f", loc2.coordinate.latitude, loc2.coordinate.longitude);

        CLLocationDistance dist = [loc distanceFromLocation:loc2];

        NSLog(@"DIST: %f", dist); 

        myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
        myAnnotation.title = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", dist];


        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
    }


    NSArray *alko = [dict objectForKey:@"Category2"];

    NSLog(@" MapView is %@",mapView);
    NSLog(@"alko is: %@", alko);


    for(int i = 0; i < [alko count]; i++) {


        NSString *coordinates = [[alko objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Coordinates"];

        double realLatitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
        double realLongitude = [[[coordinates componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];

        MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
        theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;

        myAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(realLatitude,realLongitude);        
        myAnnotation.title = [[alko objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Name"];
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [[alko objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];


        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
    }





    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Annotation

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;


    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                    initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Category1"];
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[anns objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"]];

    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;


    return pinView;
}
```

Comment: what does the string value refer to?

Comment: I have objectForKey:@"Icon" that have value of image name that I need to display. It works for one category, but I doesn't know how to do same for second category.

Comment: Im wondering what file do these code belong to? mapview.m?

Comment: Just loop anns in - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation; as you did in the viewDidLoad. I think they are in the same order. But really mess up. You would better subclass the MKAnnotation, then codes will be more readable.

Comment: Ok. Can you write an example how I loop my anns Array?

Comment: Just like what you did in the viewDidLoad, the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
NSString *theCategory;

// set theCategory to what you need.
theCategory = @"Category1"

NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:theCategory];
```

**Edit 1**

First you'd better set the annotation class as following:

**MyAnnotation.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MyAnnotation : NSManagedObject <MKAnnotation>{

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
UIImage *imageForMyAnnotation;
}

@property (nonatomic,readwrite) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *imageForMyAnnotation;
```

**MyAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
//here you can set the coordinate of your annotation
return coordinate;
}

- (UIImage *)imageForMyAnnotation{
//set the image here, i think it is depend on the coordinate right? You can put some code here to chose the category that corresponding to the coordinate
return image;
}

// optional
- (NSString *)title
{
return title;
}
- (NSString *)subtitle
{
return subtitle;
}
```

Then in your mapView, you can add the annotation with

**MapView.m**

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:myAnnotationArray];
```

or

```
[self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
```

and

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

UIImageView *annotationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myAnnotation.imageForMyAnnotatioin]; 

customPinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = annotationImageView;

}
```

Comment: but I have two categories that have different images, how can it be done?

Comment: @PavelKaljunen inView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[anns objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Icon"]]; this is your solution, the Icon stores the image's name, and they are different

Comment: Yes, I know that. But if I set theCategory = @"Category1", then my Category2 doesn't display image. I need to show both category images.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Of course you can show different image on different annotation's callout. The image is put in the leftCalloutAccessoryView right?

Comment: I mean a pin image, not the image inside annotation

Comment: @PavelKaljunen A pin image? You create your own annotation view? Or use MKPinAnnotationView? Could you plz show me more codes? ps. i have updated my answer

Comment: Can I just loop my Array's to read the category automatically from plist? Thanks for your help!